# Printing array inside array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I have class Building in which i have one class member NSMutableArray *subnode.I have declared one more array buildingArray which stores the element of type Building.I have tried to print Building class object as shown in following code.But goes in only first for loop. 
Second for loop of subnode array is not executing . Is this proper way of printing the object having the array as a one of its class member.
code:

```
    for(Building *b in buildingArray)
{
    NSLog(@"inside building array");
    for(NSString *str in b.subnode)
    {
        NSLog(@"inside subnode array");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for debugging purposes, I would recommend trying the following: Every object that inherits from `NSObject` inherits its `description` method.

Add this to `Building.m`:

```
@implementation Building

- (NSString *)description {
    NSMutableString *description = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[super description]];
    // add the following lines for any relevant properties
    // [description appendFormat:@", materials == %@", materials];
    // then have the subnode print itself:
    [description appendFormat:@", subnode == %@", subnode];
    return description;
}

@end
```

You can then print the entire `buildingArray` by simply calling the following code:

```
NSLog(@"buildingArray == %@", buildingArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following code. I don't know what do you mean buy `Building` . So i just used `id` instead of `Building` to avoid any type of confusion.

```
for(id b  in buildingArray)
{
    NSLog(@"inside building array");
    NSArray *temp = b;

    for(NSString *str in temp)
    {
        NSLog(@"inside subnode array");
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help you;

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Building *b in buildingArray)
{
NSLog(@"inside building array");
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:b.subnode]
for(id *str in temp)
{
    NSLog(@"inside subnode array");
}
}
```

this should work. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok. Just check if the array (subnode) is allocated and initialized. Also check if it has some values in it. I have used similar code and it works for me.